# Only one element of array is being passed into function. C++

Tags: c++, arrays, function, pointers, googletest

For some reason, my function `LinearSearch` is only getting the first element of the array that's being passed in. I found this by putting a breakpoint in the function and looking at the locals that it has, and I don't know why it's only getting the `7` from the array `a`. The test case I have is the following (GoogleTest):

```
TEST(LinearSearch, ElementExists2Items) {
  // LinearSearch should return a pointer to the item if it exists in the array.
  int a[2] = {7, 2};
  EXPECT_EQ(a, LinearSearch(a, 2, 7));
  EXPECT_EQ(a + 1, LinearSearch(a, 2, 2));
}
```

Here is my `LinearSearch` function:

```
int* LinearSearch(int theArray[], int size, int key) {
    if (size == 0)
        return nullptr;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (key == theArray[i])
            return (theArray);
        else
            return nullptr;
    }
}
```

Am I missing something? Do I need to pass `theArray` by reference instead? I don't know why it's only getting the first value passed into the function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are returning the very first time.

*Solution or rather a hint*

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    if (key == theArray[i])
        return (theArray);
    //if it cannot find it the very first time, it returns null IN YOUR CASE :)
}
return nullptr;
```

*Your Case*

Just think about the execution. The very first time it does not find something it immediately returns and exits the function. Hence it only sees one element.

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (key == theArray[i])
            return (theArray);
        else
            return nullptr;
    }
```

*Update*

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    if (key == theArray[i])
        return (theArray + i); 
    // you currently pass the pointer to the start of the array again and again. Pass the pointer to the element instead.
}
return null;
```

Comment: Well, now I'm getting closer, but I'm still not quite there. I moved the `return nullptr` outside of the array and added this line: `else if (key != theArray[i]) continue;`, but it still fails...just doesn't return null.

Comment: any ideas from here?

Comment: Firstly you should return (theArray + i). (theArray) only returns a pointer to the start of the array which you already have. You don't need an additional else statement. Check the update section

Comment: OOOOHHHHHH I don't know why I never thought of that. +1 thank you, you helped me figure it out!

Comment: Not a problem. Pointers troubled me a lot too. In case you want to know how I became better at it (I'm still a beginner) feel free to contact me :)